# Poking the stack

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand how exactly the stack works, so I'll recreate here a small example with some questions.

Pretend that I have a small code in ASM that does the following thing:

(all this is x86, intel syntax, Linux)

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 16

mov eax, 0xdeadbeef  <-- let's call this 'local variable a'
mov [ebp - 16], eax

mov eax, 0xabcdabcd  <-- let's call this 'local variable b'
mov [ebp - 12], eax

mov eax, 0xcacafafa  <-- let's call this 'local variable c'
mov [ebp - 8], eax

mov eax, 0xdada1111  <-- let's call this 'local variable d'
mov [ebp - 4], eax

call 0x10101010 <------- pretend that is the real address of function_B

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Now pretend that I have a C function called `function_B` which get's called from the asm code and it looks like this:

```
asmlinkage void function_B(void){

    //some code here...

}
```

How would I access `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` from `function_B` with inline ASM code?

Would this work? Should I be doing it differently?

```
uint32_t val_a;
__asm__ __volatile__(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "mov %0, dword [ebp + 4 + 4 + 0];"
    ".att_syntax;"
    : "=r" (val_a)
);

uint32_t val_b;
__asm__ __volatile__(
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "mov %0, dword [ebp + 4 + 4 + 4];"
    ".att_syntax;"
    : "=r" (val_b)
);
```

Also, how would I access `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` if my function looked like this:

```
asmlinkage void function_B(unsigned int val){

    //some code here...

}
```

Comment: I think reading ebp value via inline assembly and should try to access those variables via bp indexing, as you've already sorted out.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey poking, yes! Thank. rakib: would that work for both function_b declarations?

Comment: yes, it should. AFAIK, asmlinkage tells compiler to look for variables into stack and perhaps it's more of an issue related to linkage.

Comment: What about passing the addresses of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` as parameters to the `function_B`? Depending on optimization level GCC could create a varying local stack frame for `function_B`.

Comment: @harper Thing is I don't want to pass arguments, that's not the point of my question. The point of my question is how to poke the caller's stack.

Comment: Read wikipage on [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: A trick about using intel syntax with asm in gcc: you can write it like this: `__asm__ __volatile__("{|mov %0, dword [ebp + 4 + 4 + 4]}" : "=r" (val_b));`.  To understand why this works, see "Using braces in asm templates" in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate.  Is this "better?"  Well, it produces the same code, but is a bit shorter, so mostly it's a question of style.  Also, your code "puts things back" with att_syntax, but that assumes att_syntax is the current default, which isn't guaranteed (see -masm compile switch). Also, I wouldn't use volatile here.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
void function_B(uint32_t fake){
    uint32_t* poke = &fake;
    uint32_t a = poke[0];
    uint32_t b = poke[1];
    uint32_t c = poke[2];
    uint32_t d = poke[3];
}
```

What will give you the values of a, b, c and d with your current asm code (which is not pushing any arguments to function_B). If you also want to pass real arguments to function_B you can still add the fake one after the last real argument:

```
void function_B(unsigned int val,uint32_t fake)
```

It is actually a little safer to do it like this (then with inline asm) since it has a better chance to survive optimizations (like stack frame omission). But it's still a hack of course, and nothing I would rely too much upon.