# Size of stack frame on Linux -- is it always static

Tags: c, linux

To make the question more concrete, consider the below example (and let's say I turned off all the optimization so that my dummy functions won't be optimized away):

```
#include <stdint.h>

void func0() { int32_t a = 0; }
void func1() { int32_t a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4; }
void func2() { int32_t a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}; }

int main(void) {
  func0();
  func1();
  func2();
  return 0;
}
```

I have three functions, `func1`/`func2`/`func3` and variables defined inside them occupy different amount of memory space (i.e., `func1` uses 4 bytes, `func2` uses 20 bytes and `func3` uses 40 bytes).

My question is: for one function call, my program always uses the amount of memory equivalent to the size of a stack frame, regardless of the actual space needed for variable?

To put it another way, for the program to call either `func1`, `func2` or `func3`, it will use exactly the same amount of memory?

Comment: From [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501222/finding-stack-frame-size), I would say no.

Comment: @ChristopheQuintard I actually found this and I tried compiling the code. `(char *)__builtin_frame_address(1) - (char *)__builtin_frame_address(0)` gives me 16. But I am not sure how exactly should I interpret this...

Comment: If a function using 20 bytes of local data would take same space on stack as a function using 500kB of local data that would rather quickly exhaust your stack. That would also require that the maximum size of local data across all functions (also in other compilation units) would be known, to start with.

Comment: The OS did not allocate memory for a function call. You have one stack for each thread and the program ( not any OS call ) uses this memory simply by shifting the stack pointers.  And the stack size can be configured by a function call which reallocates the required memory.

Comment: @Gerhardh  for the first part, sure, it wastes more space, but for the 2nd part, I think it is just the opposite: the compiler doesnt care how much we use, it just allocates a fixed amount of memory for each function call, if my function uses too much, OS just emit a segment fault.

Comment: @Klaus revised my incorrect wording

Comment: this is just a hypothesis, if you dont like it, you are free to come up with yours.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thanks for let me know--otherwise I think I know everything already, so that I open a new SO question just to troll you. If you dont want your intelligence to be insulted by my silly question, free feel to shut up and leave.

Comment: you are not invited to my comment dedicated to another person, please just find another question to lecture your school of hypothesis verification.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: for one function call, my program always uses the amount of memory equivalent to the size of a stack frame, regardless of the actual space needed for variable?

No!

First at all:
The stack is allocated before a thread starts and you have one stack per thread in your application. The size of the stack can be ( OS dependent ) modified by function calls or by other settings ( depending on used tool chain / compiler / linker / OS ). It is fully different for embedded or PC style computers.

There is no OS call for the use of a stack frame for a function call! The ABI ( application binary interface ) for your compiler/OS defines how the stack frame looks like, how variables are placed there, if it uses gap bytes or starts always with a specific alignment or not.

As more variables you pass, the stack frame for the call increases. But: If the compiler generated function did not need the parameters because they can be optimized out, only the needed parameters are passed. In a lot of cases functions are completely inlined, which means no function call and no stack frame needed. If your ABI defines a stack starts always on a 64bit alignment, it looks like a fixed size of stack frames. But this is still dynamic, because it takes more space if needed.

In a short:
Size of stack frame is fully dynamic.

But:
Why you should care about? It can't be changed without braking the ABI, which means you can't call functions of libraries etc. and you can be guaranteed that your compiler will generate a well optimized stack layout for you.

Comment: This question is actually a precursor of my real question. If stack frame is fully dynamic, then why do we need heap? Let's just do `int32_t arr[1000 * 1000]` instead. What prevents us from just doing this?

Comment: You need heap to put data in it which will persists over function calls. Data on stack can only be used in the next level of function calls. Even if you pass data from one function call to another, the compiler needs ( if not optimized away ) to copy the data on the next stack frame for the nested call, Using heap is simply fully different from stack and has nothing todo with the dynamic size.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind How would you return that memory to your caller? There are different lifetime rules for local variables and dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Return values and life time has nothing to do with each other. Return values are copied to the memory of the caller before the function ends ( old version ) or optimized by "Return value optimization RVO). This is guaranteed by current c++ standard. No need to use heap allocated memory to pass back data. In general you can't reference local memory back to the caller.

Comment: @Klaus using heap is for sure fully different. What I want to achieve is to eliminate dynamic heap allocation in C so that we will greatly reduce the risk of memory leak. In current design, we just cant have `int32_t arr[1000 * 1000]` given stack frame's size limit, regardless of persistence.

Comment: (and let's limit the scope of the issue to C though, C++ have RAII already, let's consider memory leak as problem solved, for the purpose of this question at least...)

Comment: As already said: You can increase the stack size for your thread/application. There is no technical reason which stops you from using a very big stack. But it is very uncommon! Why you did not change to c++? Simply use auto pointers and most of your leak problems are history!

Comment: excuse me? I think why not changing to C++ is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Not of this question, but it is in general. Instead reinventing the wheel and fighting against long time solved problems, you may think of switching your toolbox.